# Store radiobutton checkedvalue in variable with TSQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, checked

I have a webform with a textfield.

The webform is connected to an integral database. But for this I don't need to store the value from this radiobutton into a table. I just want to take that value, and use it as a return for another field, just like it was not connected to a database at all.

In my TSQL code I assigned this textfield to a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @vak1 int
SET @vak1 = '[field name='vak1']'.
```

'field name' is the name of the object of that textfield. And I named it vak1.

I also want to put the checkedvalue from a radiobutton control into a variable, just like I did in the example above. But I dont know the name of the object, like in the above example it is field name for a textfield. So I need to know the standard name of a radiobutton object. These are all being used as LOCAL variables.

For example:

```
DECLARE @radio int
SET @radio = '[ x  = 'No_cure_no_pay']'
```

The name No_cure_no_pay is the name of the radiobutton object. But what should I call x here? In the upper example it is 'field name' for a text field webcontrol.

What is the name for a radio button webcontrol?

The software I am using is custom made 3rd party software by a local Dutch company and it is not well known. So I cannot provide much info on the internals of the database. I don't have much code. Just these two lines would suffice, because the rest is pretty much the same just with different variable names. I will just use the values as return values. Just need to know how to declare and set a checked radiobutton value.

Comment: What do you actually want to know? How to save the value to the database, what datatype to use, or something else? You might want to provide a bit more information.

Comment: I want to put the value from a checkedbutton from a webform in a variable but not for the purpose of storing it in a database. Just want to use it as a local variable hence the code writing in Tsql. for example I have this for a fieldname declaration.
SET @vak1 = '[field name='vak1']'

Comment: I want to do this also for a radio button object. So in the above example it is "field name" for a textbox. and I want to know the name for a radio button object.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are after. Please update your question with more details and code examples.

Comment: I have a webform. Therein I have a textfield. In my TSQL code I assigned this textfield to a variable like this: 
DECLARE @vak1 int
SET @vak1 = '[field name='vak1']'.  
'field name' is the name of the object of that textfield. and I named it vak1.

I also want to put the checkedvalue from a radiobutton control`into a variable, just like I did in the example above. But I dont know the name of the object, like in the above example it is field name for a textfield. So I need to know the standard name of a radiobutton object. These are all being used as LOCAL variables.

Comment: @SteveDowling understands this. But the point he is trying to make is saying "a webform" is most ambiguous a best. How is the webform created? How are you connecting the webform to your database? Is it local web storage or external? Providing as much code that you've already written and as much detail will help us to help you. Hope you understand.

Comment: Thanks Johnny for elaborating. So this webform is just a webcontrol form. And it just for local web storage. The software Iam using is custom made 3th party software by a local dutch company and it is not well known. I dont have much code. Just these two lines would suffice, because the rest is pretty much the same just with different variable names. I will just use the values as return values.

Comment: The webform is indeed connected to a integral database. But for this I dont need to store the value from this radiobutton into a table. I just want to take that value, and use it as a return for another field. Hope it is clear. If not could you please ask more info

Comment: It basically comes down to this:
How can I declare and set the value from a radiobutton object just like I declared it for a textfield (in the above example)?

Comment: update your question with all the information you provided in several comments, please