# How can I declare and set the value from a radiobutton object with TSQL syntax?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, webforms, radio-button

I have a webform with a textfield.

The webform is connected to an integral database. But for this I don't need to store the value from this radiobutton into a table. I just want to take that value, and use it as a return for another field, just like it was not connected to a database at all.

In my TSQL code I assigned this textfield to a variable like this:

```
DECLARE @vak1 int
SET @vak1 = '[field name='vak1']'.
```

`'field name'` is the name of the object of that textfield. And I named it `vak1`.

I also want to put the checkedvalue from a radiobutton control into a variable, just like I did in the example above. But I dont know the name of the object, like in the above example it is field name for a textfield. So I need to know the standard name of a radiobutton object. These are all being used as LOCAL variables.

For example:

```
DECLARE @radio int
SET @radio = '[ x  = 'No_cure_no_pay']'
```

The name `No_cure_no_pay` is the name of the radiobutton object. But what should I call x here? In the upper example it is `'field name'` for a text field webcontrol.

What is the name for a radio button webcontrol?

The software I am using is custom made 3rd party software by a local Dutch company and it is not well known. So I cannot provide much info on the internals of the database. I don't have much code. Just these two lines would suffice, because the rest is pretty much the same just with different variable names. I will just use the values as return values. Just need to know how to declare and set a checked radiobutton value.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841291/store-radiobutton-checkedvalue-in-variable-with-tsql

Comment: Was there another way to update my question as A ツ stated?

Comment: Use the edit button.